# How can I apply MYSQL restriction for spaces in field values?

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, validation

I have validation of required field on invoice number text box and validation is working perfectly for empty text box. But when spaces is added to the text box it skips validation. I have used regular expression to check spaces and thrown valid validation but my question is there any way I can do this on database field also.

Comment: How is this a MYSQL issue? What is the code you are using for validation currently?

Comment: It is not Mysql issue. I want to know is there any way I can set restriction through Mysql

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a way - it is a dirty hack and I don't recommend using it unless there is no other way to do it. Basically you create a trigger - I wanted to code to throw an error but it seems you can't do that on mysql directly so the code tries to delete from a table that doesn't exist.

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER check_mycolumn_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON `my_table`
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.mycolumn like '% %') THEN
       DELETE FROM your_meaningfull_message WHERE id=-1;
    END IF;
END$$
```

Comment: I tested if with an insert:

INSERT INTO `my_table` (`mycolumn`) VALUES ('bl abl abl');

and I get an error:

Error Code: 1146. Table 'test_db.your_meaningfull_message' doesn't exist

Comment: Thanks @ljubiccia. I am happy with javascript validation for blank space.

Comment: You are welcome. And I think that is a better way! =)
Just for your info - on other databases there is a CHECK constraint, that can be used for this but in mysql the CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines (dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html).

Comment: @Abhilasha if you still get white spaces from your text boxes you should consider both of my answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove them like this:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`col_name`) VALUES (REPLACE( 'a string you are inserting' , ' ' , '' ));
```

Comment: I have to restrict record to save if it contain spaces for field value. At present I have used regular expression to check spaces in field value but still i want to know if there is anyway to set  restriction through MySql